# How does a Hidden Mist ninja have the Byakugan?

Tags: naruto

We know that the *Byakugan* is the dōjutsu kekkei genkai of the Hyūga clan of the Hidden Leaf. And each village does its best to try and keep such coveted powers to themselves.

But in a recent filler episode of Shippuden, Episode 358 to be exact, a ninja from the Hidden Mist was shown to have used the Byakugan and could locate Uchicha Shisui, thereby asking his team to retreat. How does a ninja from a village other than the Hidden Leaf and not of the Hyūga bloodline have the Byakugan?

Is this for real or is it just another mistake by the animators? Is there a mention of such a ninja in the manga(I follow only the anime and not the manga)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a mention of such a ninja in the manga as well as in the earlier episodes of the anime.

The ninja that you are referring to is [Ao](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ao).

> He has clashed several times with Konoha shinobi. At one point he
>   defeated an unknown Hyūga, taking one of the Hyūga's Byakugan and
>   implanting it into his own right eye socket. Later, he had a
>   confrontation with Shisui Uchiha, which left enough of an impact on Ao
>   for him to clearly remember Shisui's abilities and his chakra colour
>   long after the event.

He first appeared in the manga chapter 454 and Naruto Shippuden anime episode 199 (the five kage summit arc)